# How to convert an array to a List<string> to pass correct parameter to Controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following javascript code:

```
 var groupArray = [];
      groupArray.push($("#group").val());
      var sendInfo = { Id: 0,
         Name: $("#disc-name").val(),
         Groups: groupArray,
         Description: $("#disc-description").val()
      };
$.post('/Home/Add', sendInfo, function(msg) { alert(msg.data }, 'json');
```

The Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
       public JsonResult Add(Something parameters) {

          return Json( new {
             data = _something.AddSomething(parameters)
          },
          JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
       }
```

and `Something` model is:

```
public string Name {
         get;
         set;
      }

      public List<string> Groups {
         get;
         set;
      }

      public int Id {
         get;
         set;
      }

      public string Url {
         get {
            return FriendlyUrl.Slugify( this.Name );
         }
      }

      public string Description {
         get;
         set;
      }
```

In debug mode, when I want to send `sendInfo` object via AJAX, I see that `Groups` is null (in Controller page).

I want to know if something is wrong or is other way to do tricks in Javascript code. I don't want to change the `Something` model structure.

Thank you

Comment: I think jquery's $.post will serialize arrays by putting an extra "[]" after the name of the array. In your example, your post data will contain Groups[]=1&Groups[]=5&Groups[]=74... (for example). Since you cannot use brackets in variable names in C# I do not know how to get around this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `JSON.stringify` like this

```
$.post('/Home/Add', JSON.stringify(sendInfo), function(msg) { alert(msg.data }, 'json');
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify` where I could find this function ? in JSON library (https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) ?

Comment: because now it works, there was my fault :). Whatever, JSON.Stringify is good idea ... Sorry for confusion :)  PS: Upvoted and accepted :)